# Why Vega 3 is not working with Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, visualization, vega

I am trying to use [**Vega v3**](https://github.com/vega/vega) into a very basic **Angular v2** skeleton (using **typescript v2** and **webpack v2**), but obtaining unexpected behavior, which I will try to explain below (from here I will omit versions, but the reference will be [those specified here](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/blob/27bb1d85efa83b3f3e4cbdd08b5ac7dcdfa6dd3d/package.json#L25-L81)).

[Full demo repo here.](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega)

- First, the bundled version wasn't working for me so I decided to include every dependency listed in [a provided example](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/package.json#L55-L74) and [using Vega modules directly](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/blob/27bb1d85efa83b3f3e4cbdd08b5ac7dcdfa6dd3d/src/vega/vega.component.ts#L5-L7).
- Second, there were three official example specifications ([first spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/spec/bar.vg.json), [second spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/web/prefacet.html#L27-L110), [third spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/web/group.html#L33-L116)) used to test the described setup.
- Third, after running [the base Vega drawing methods chain](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/blob/27bb1d85efa83b3f3e4cbdd08b5ac7dcdfa6dd3d/src/vega/vega.component.ts#L74-L86) for each specification, the results were of two types:

  - [first spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/spec/bar.vg.json), throws the following error: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./VegaPlotComponent class VegaPlotComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'orient' of undefined` which breaks entire Angular app. [Full stack trace here](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/issues/1).
  - [second spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/web/prefacet.html#L27-L110) & [third spec](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/6ab84d83a23e66f38e9fcd3586dc8a57cf9349c7/web/group.html#L33-L116) create a `width="9", height="9"` svg square without apparent reason ([2nd spec plot size](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/blob/27bb1d85efa83b3f3e4cbdd08b5ac7dcdfa6dd3d/src/vega/vega.component.ts#L183-L184), [3rd spec plot size](https://github.com/dbautistav/ng2-vega/blob/27bb1d85efa83b3f3e4cbdd08b5ac7dcdfa6dd3d/src/vega/vega.component.ts#L290-L291)) as shown in fig-1 and fig-2.

[image: screenshot from 2016-11-08 21-26-44]

*Figure 1. Vega plot-Angular component DOM fragment inspected (dev-tools).*

[image: screenshot from 2016-11-08 21-34-25]

*Figure 2. Vega plot-Angular component DOM fragment selected (rendered view).*

**So, why Vega 3 is not working with Angular2?**

Comment: Have you tried this directive "https://github.com/limalimacharlie/ng-vega3" ?

Comment: That suggestion is based on AngularJS (aka angular 1), and I wanted to use angular 2+.

Comment: https://github.com/kristina-albrecht/angular5-vega-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [an issue at the official github repo](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/656) same week I posted this question here, but they closed it like six months ago because major changes have been developed since I asked about.

Currently there are many libraries that can do that.